# Measuring sensor noise on analog channels of common single board computers

Tags: arduino, analog, noise, signal-processing, matlab

Using the "MATLAB support package for Arduino" package, I am trying to characterise the analog input channels on an Arduino Uno board. The underlying assumption is that all sensors are inherently noisy and far from perfect. After all, the arduino has got only a 10-bit ADC, and there should be at-least some quantization noise, if not pick-up electrical noise.

But when I ground any of the 5 analog pins on the Uno (i.e. a hook-up wire connected between analog channels and the on-board GND pin), all that MATLAB can read in software is a perfectly flat '0' (ideal voltage) even after collecting analog data for long time-periods. This seems a bit strange to me, as the analog sensor on the Arduino is certainly not super hi-fidelity.

i would really like to characterize the analog channels (for coming up with the "R" (i.e. sensor covariance) matrix when I later implement a Kalman filter using batch analog data collected from this Arduino. Any help towards this is much appreciated.

Comment: What are you using for the ADC reference? if it is 5V then one LSB will be 4.88 mV, so any noise less than that may not show up. Also I found that the ATmega328 used on the Arduino Uno has an ADC noise canceler feature, not sure if this is used by MATLAB package.

Comment: Yes. Indeed you are right. I am using the 5V internal reference. I am also unsure if MATLAB is using the ADC noise canceler or not

Comment: I believe that noise reduction is disabled Uno bu default. The user has to change the appropriate register values in a sketch. So it is safe to assume that Uno is not applying noise reduction. Additionally, the Atmel spec estimates the accuracy of the onboard ADC to be +/- 2 LSB. For a ten bit ADC, that's +/- 9.76mV. This could be a great place to start in estimating covariance. You can model the noise as Gaussian centered around 0, with 95% of the data falling between +/- 9.76 mV of the true value.